# Swift using eratosthenes method to get prime numbers

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to use [eratosthenes method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

to get prime numbers with swift. I create first function to return new array without those numbers that can be divided for specific multiplier, then create second function to create new array every time with new P multiplier. I wonder why its not work (look like it somehow pass old array, i dont know why). It should print new array of prime numbers at the end:

```
 var simpleArr : [Int] = []

for i in 2...100 {
    simpleArr.append(i)
}


func arrayEcludingDivingByP (p: Int, arrToCheck : [Int]) -> Array<Int>{

    var  tmp : [Int] = []

    for (ob, index) in arrToCheck.enumerated() {

        var isDividible : Bool = ob % p == 0 ? true : false

        if (!isDividible){
            tmp.append(ob)
        }
    }

    return tmp
}

var p : Int = 2


func getSimpleNumbersArrayFromArray (p : Int, arrPassed : [Int]) -> Array <Int>{

    var tmp : [Int] = []

    var newArr = arrayEcludingDivingByP(p: p, arrToCheck: arrPassed)

    if (newArr.isEmpty){
        // No more p availible, just return tmp

    }   else {
        let newP = p + 1
        getSimpleNumbersArrayFromArray(p: newP, arrPassed: newArr)
        tmp = newArr
        print("tmp array? \(tmp)")

    }

    return tmp


}

getSimpleNumbersArrayFromArray(p: p, arrPassed: simpleArr)
```

In console it prints:

```
tmp array? [1]
tmp array? [1, 2]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23]
tmp array? [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31]
tmp array? [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47]
tmp array? [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97]
```

But it suppose to print final iteration with tmp filled with prime numbers. What did i wrong?

Comment: Note that this is *not* the Eratosthenes sieve (which does no divisibility tests `%` at all, only multiplications).

Comment: @MartinR, good point about this not being the Eratosthenes sieve, but the Eratosthenes sieve doesn't use multiplications either.  It finds the multiples of `p` by repeatedly adding `p`.

Comment: @vacawama: Yes, "it computes multiples" is what I meant. (And if you start with p*p then you need a multiplication as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `newArr` to represent the values in the sieve that remain.  Your `tmp` array should be the primes found so far.  Also you are using a recursive call which is confusing.  I suggest simply grabbing the first value out of `newArr` which is a prime, add that prime to your list of primes, and then call `arrayEcludingDividingByP` to filter out the non-primes divisible by that prime. Repeat until `newArr` isEmpty which will happen when the *conditional binding* statement `while let newP = newArr.first` fails and the loop ends:

```
func getPrimes(arrPassed: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var primes: [Int] = []
    var newArr = arrPassed

    while let newP = newArr.first {
        primes.append(newP)
        newArr = arrayEcludingDivingByP(p: newP, arrToCheck: newArr)
    }

    return primes
}

print(getPrimes(arrPassed: Array(2...100)))
```

This can be further optimized because once `newP * newP` is greater than the largest number in `newArr` (`newArr.last!)` you are done and you can simply append `newArr` to `primes` and set `newArr` to `[]`.

Also, `arrayEcludingDivingByP(p: newP, arrToCheck: newArr)` can be replaced by `newArr.filter { $0 % newP != 0 }`

Comment: have you try it? it prints only [2, 1]

Comment: Have I tried *it*? What are you referring to exactly, my last comment? It does need to be assigned to `newArr`. So `newArr = newArr.filter { $0 % newP != 0 }`.